# Rails mass assignment: extra brackets from where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Assuming near-identical view, controller and models (except for names, obviously), how would you get this params output in your cli:

```
$ "project"=>{"genres_projects_attributes"=>{"genre_id"=>["1"]}
```

versus this params output:

```
$"user"=>{"production_media_users_attributes"=>[{"production_medium_id"=>["1"]}]}
```

Note the additional brackets [] in the second line.  The first line works.  The second line does not.  There is no error message.

source code below, but looks identical to me:
controller

```
def user_params
  params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:id, production_media_users_attributes: [:id, :user_id, {production_medium_id: []}])
end

def project_params
    params.fetch(:project, {}).permit(:id, genres_projects_attributes: [:id, :project_id, {genre_id: []}])
end
```

models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :production_media, through: :production_media_users
    has_many :production_media_users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :production_media_users
end

class ProductionMedium < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: :production_media_users
    has_many :production_media_users
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :genres, through: :genres_projects
    has_many :genres_projects
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :genres_projects
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects, through: :genres_projects
    has_many :genres_projects
end
```

views

```
<%= select_tag 'user[production_media_users_attributes][][production_medium_id][]', options_for_select(ProductionMedium.order(:id).collect{|g| [g.name, g.id]}), { include_hidden: true, multiple: true,  required: true, placeholder: 'Choose One or More', class: 'form-control menu-select2'} %>

<%= select_tag 'project[genres_projects_attributes][][genre_id][]', options_for_select(Genre.order(:id).collect{|g| [g.name, g.id]}), { include_hidden: true, multiple: true,  required: true, placeholder: 'Choose One or More', class: 'form-control menu-select2'} %>
```

Comment: Can we troubleshoot this a bit?  It is puzzling as to why both select_tags do not post the same params.  Are you using the same type of form on both selects?  Are they both form_for or form_tag?  Try this, get rid of the leading '[]' just after [production_media_users_attributes] and you will get rid of the array you are speaking of.  Then look back at the project params and see if you can influence it to have the brackets.

Comment: thanks for responding.  I have since just hacked a solution as I didn't want to spend more time on it.  if i were to troubleshoot it further, I would probably see whether one method calls a patch versus a get, is causing the difference.  FYI, I did delete the [] as you pointed out, which does influence the params.

Comment: Oh well, this means you have to go and do something crazy this weekend.  Peace Allen!

Answer (score 0):

theres an extra colon on production_media_users_attributes, is that it?

```
params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:id, :production_media_users_attributes:
```